# Split data into adjacent cells upon entry EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to split data in excel that has been entered in from an external source.  The external source puts all the data into one cell.  I would like this data to be split based on the spaces between the information.  I have a macro that splits all the data in the sheet but if the there is any data that is already split it gets deleted.

Is there a way to run a macro like this when data is entered without user input?

Below is the macro
Sub splits()

```
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 3), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 3), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you share an example of one of these compacted cell's data? That would help me to test any code I build for you.

Comment: So you have a program, which puts external information into a single cell. You want to split that information while working on that cell. Although I understand your point, it is wrong: you should make sure that the program puts the external information already in different cells. (Doing such things afterwards have the tendency of causing problems with wrong delimiters, ...)

Comment: Example information that is put into the cell is         Gypsum 222 8/6/22 -1 9/6/22 12:30

Comment: Dominique I agree with you on that but I have no way of altering the external data

Comment: How is the external data being imported into Excel?  There a tons of options for external data sources that allow for this sort of thing.

Comment: It is coming from a third party app that is not currently supported for excel 2013.